# Issues adding values in dictionary when attempting to append key,value pairs

Tags: python

I am attempting to list directories downstream and assign a value to them in the order they were iterated through after using the os.walk command. The problem is I get a bunch of empty "{}" values following the desired result.

```
import os
path = "PATH\\TO\\DIRECTORY\\"
os.chdir(path)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
ij = 1
dir_output = {}
for dir in dirs:
    dir_output[ij] = dir
    ij += 1
print dir_output
```

I get the following result:

```
{'1': 'Value1', '2': 'Value2', '3': 'Value3'}
{}
{}
{}
```

I am trying to get rid of those empty "{}" but it appears it is something specific to the os.walk output. Tried .pop and .strip but just got errors.

Comment: Use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead.

Comment: This for loop is why you get the empty dictionaries: `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path)`. You might want to format your code so that we can more easily read it since, for example, it's ambiguous where your print statement is.

Comment: Try moving `dir_output = {}` above your `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path)`

Answer (score 0):

By moving the initializing of `ij` and `dir_output` outside of the for loop, you can skip the additional empty dictionaries:

```
import os
path = "PATH\\TO\\DIRECTORY\\"
os.chdir(path)
dir_output = {}
ij = 1
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
  for dir_ in dirs:
    dir_output[ij] = dir_
    ij += 1
print dir_output
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried that. It didn't work as planned.

Here's how I solved it:

Instead of using os.walk I did:

```
for dir in os.listdir('.'):
```

That way, it only iterates through the dirs. 
I didn't want enumeration because I will be mapping dictionary values into options on a menu. Now, the last thing to come is mapping those values in rows of three instead of one per row.